# Counting preceding/succeeding cell values in a range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, countif

I am trying to figure out how to write a formula to count preceding and succeeding cell values of a specific value in a range. Here is an example:

For this column, how many times does "black" come before "red", how many times does "green" come before "yellow", etc?

[Color List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9MqN.jpg)

Comment: Please also show in a picture or text table in the original post how you would expect the output to look

Comment: And when you say before, anywhere before or the cell directly above?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how many times does "black" appear in the cell immediately before "red" and "green" in the cell immediately before "yellow" then this will work:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A14,"red",A1:A13,"black")+COUNTIFS(A2:A14,"yellow",A1:A13,"green")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a stab in the dark as to what you are looking for,  This will count based on the grid, how many are in adjacent cells.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$1040001,$C2,$A$2:$A$1040002,D$1),COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$1040001,D$1,$A$2:$A$1040002,$C2))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a clever formula, however the way it's presented it duplicates the results, which makes the results inaccurate and difficult to read. Suggest to use only one of the components of the formula (i.e. `COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$1040001,$C2,$A$2:$A$1040002,D$1)`) that way cell `D5` will show `2` meaning _black_ is twice before _red_ (o viceversa) while  cell `G2` will show 1 meaning _black_ is once after _read_ (o viceversa).

Comment: Just out of curiosity why using `$A$1:$A$1040001` and `$A$1:$A$1040001` instead of just `$A$1:$A$16` and `$A$2:$A$17`?

Comment: @EEM according to the OP, they want to know each time that the colors are before or after.  So look at Red/Yellow, there is twice that Red either precedes yellow or follows yellow, in fact one each.  If I do only one it would only pick up one and not the other, yes on the Black Black it counts the same two twice but by the rules set forth it should as Black precedes black and black follows black.  I did the references that way so it is close to full columns and do not need to be adjusted if more colors are added,  This is not an array formula so it is okay to have the full area.

Answer (score 0):

If you merely want to count the occurrence of one color before the **1-st** occurrence of another color then you might be done with the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:INDEX(A2:A16,MATCH(E2,A2:A16,0)),C2)
```

[image]

But if you wish to cound the occurrence of one color before the **n-th** occurrence of another color then you are probably looking for the following solution:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:INDEX(A2:A16,SMALL(IF(A2:A16=E2,ROW(A2:A16)-ROW(INDEX(A2:A16,1,1))+1),D2)),C2)
```

[image]

Note, that the second formula is an array formula and must be entered using `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`.